# WebSocket, STOMP Java Spring Boot server, client .NET C#

Tags: javascript, java, c#, spring-boot, websocket

Мною был написан Server, на Java и Spring Boot, с конфигураций WebSocket и протокола STOMP

```
...
server.servlet.context-path=/MessageAlertPool
...

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

}
```

Используя JS, в Web морде приложения я без проблем подключаюсь используя WebSocket по протоколу STOMP и получаю нужные сообщения, используя вот такой код

```
function connect(context) {
    var socket = new SockJS(context+'/websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/alert', function (alertMessageDTO) {
            let body = JSON.parse(alertMessageDTO.body);
            showMessage(body, true);
        });
    }, function(message) {
        setConnected(false)
    });
}
```

Тут используется JS библиотеки, SockJS и Stomp , при работе их в связке происходит следующее

1. По протоколу http библиотека SockJS делает запрос GET Вида

   http://myhost.com/MessageAlertPool/websocket/info?t=1615879805194
2. Получив в ответ JSON {"entropy":810556115,"origins":["*:*"],"cookie_needed":true,"websocket":true} уже Stomp делает запрос по протоколу ws

   ws://myhost.com/MessageAlertPool/websocket/653/jas03mad/websocket

На основании чего бала сформирована та часть URL которая находится после моего Endpoint я не понимаю, всё это было проделано этими 2мя JS библиотеками, и всё работает.

Но основной целью было использование WebSocket при подключении используя .NET и C#
Используя примеры озвученный в [ПРИМЕР](https://github.com/chen0040/spring-websocket-csharp-client-demo) я пытаюсь подключится к

```
ws://myhost.com/MessageAlertPool/websocket
```

На что получаю :

```
Fatal|WebSocket.connect:0|WebSocketSharp.WebSocketException: Not a WebSocket handshake response.
                             в WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.doHandshake()
                             в WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.connect()
```

Что закономерно, т.к. не было осуществлено 1е рукопожатие по протоколу http и не было запроса info?t=хххххххххх

Есть [Описание](https://habr.com/ru/post/343908/) работы JS библиотек

Есть реализация для .NET [SockJS](https://github.com/sypbiz/SockJS.NET) а также несколько реализаций [Stomp.NET](https://github.com/DaveSenn/Stomp.Net) , [StompNET](https://github.com/krlito/StompNet), и другие, но как их подружить между собой я не понимаю :(

Если можно приведите пример взаимодействия WebSocket, STOMP, C# , который бы повторял логику реализации на JS